# Subdomain redirection w/ c-panel, Wordpress problem

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I use GoDaddy c-panel subdomain redirect. It creates a directory
`example.com/sub.example.com` with htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/My_Target_Wordpress_File/" [R=301,L]
```

This usually works. Visitors to
sub.example.com
are sent to `http://www. example.com/My_Target_Wordpress_File/`

But for one subdomain this does not work. Visitors are sent to another file, previously used for redirects. I have deleted and recreated the faulty subdomain.

Where is the problem? How do I make this redirect work?

I tried rewrites in the document root but to no avail.

Comment: _“Visitors are sent to another file, previously used for redirects.”_ - have you first of all made sure this is not just your browser cache tricking you? Check what happens in a private window.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe you solved it in no time. I have been AFK for a couple of years now. No more excuses. Problem solved. Should we write an answer or just let the mods archive it in the round basket?  :)